# Biblatex display references as Section also in toc

Tags: biblatex, table-of-contents, bibliographies, sectioning

I am using the `biblatex` package with

```
\usepackage[numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

and I would like the output of `\printbibliography` to be treated as a Section. In particular, I would like it to be numbered and to appear in the Table of Contents. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

`biblatex` does not interface with `tocbibind`. It has its own options to control the typesetting of the bibliography heading. The main option you want to look at is `\printbibliography`'s `heading`.

With `heading=bibnumbered,` you get a numbered heading in the bibliography (this is usually done by just using `\section` or `\chapter` to typeset the heading). There are several other possible values for the `heading` option and with KOMA-Script classes and to some degree also `memoir` the default `heading=bibliography,` also takes into account class settings regarding the bibliography heading.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Lorem}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered]
\end{document}
```

[image: ToC with bibliography numbered.]

---

In case you have several `\printbibliography`s in your document or you prefer to apply such settings in the document preamble you could use `\DeclarePrintbibliographyDefaults` to make `heading=bibnumbered` the default for all `\printbibliography` calls in your document (at least if your `biblatex` is new enough, the command was added in v3.13 from 2019-08-17).

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclarePrintbibliographyDefaults{heading=bibnumbered}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Lorem}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```